# How to use batch parameter modifiers on a variable rather than a parameter

Tags: parameters, batch-file

The syntax %~f1 modifies a parameter representing a filename into its fully qualified path. Is there a way to get that functionality for variables defined within the batch script, and not just for parameter values?

For example, if a user provides a command line parameter "test.txt", the following script works:
    echo Qualified filename: %~f1

But if I try to do the same thing with a variable instead of a parameter, how can I get the same functionality? This attempt is invalid syntax and does not work:
    set unqualifiedFilename="test.txt"
    echo Qualified filename: %~funqualifiedFilename

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The simplest way I can think of is to just use a `FOR` command.

Sample batch script:

```
@echo off
setlocal
set FileName=test.cmd

for %%i in (%FileName%) do set FullPath=%%~fi

echo Original param was '%FileName%'; full path is '%FullPath%'
```

Sample output:

```
Original param was 'test.cmd'; full path is 'C:\test.cmd'
```

Answer (score 4):

A second way is to call a function and use the %1 ... %n parameter

```
@echo off
set FileName=test.cmd
call :GetFullPath %FileName%

echo Original param was '%FileName%'; full path is '%FullPath%'
goto :eof

:GetFullPath
set "FullPath=%~f1"
goto :eof
```